# Sequences of 0s and 1s are compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be the space of sequences $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n,...)$ such that $x_i = 0$ or $x_i=1$, equipped with the metric $$d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left| x_n - y_n \right|.$$ Prove that $(X,d)$ is both complete and compact.

---

*Attempt:* Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$m,n > N \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left| x_n - x_m \right| < \epsilon.$$ Consider that \begin{eqnarray*} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left| x_n - x_m \right| & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left| x_n - x + x - x_m \right| \\
& \leq & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left| x_n - x \right| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\left| x-x_m \right| \\
& \leq & \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&=& \frac{2}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty.
\end{eqnarray*} Therefore, $x_n \to x$, and $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.

---

How do we then show that $X$ is compact with respect to this metric?

Comment: In your equation, what is $x$ and how do you obtain the strict inequality?

Comment: $x$ is the proposed limit of the sequence and it shouldn't be a strict inequality.

Comment: Yes, but what is $x$? I see that it's now not strict anymore, but how do you obtain that? Obviously $|x_n-x|\leq 1$ for each $n$, but why is the sum of the whole series less than $2^{-n}$?

Comment: You should construct such an $x$ and then show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, you can find an $N$ such that whenever $n \geq N$, you must have $d(x,x_n)< \varepsilon$

Comment: You should be writing

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \left| x_n(k) - x_m(k) \right| < \epsilon$$

or something like that.

Comment: How would I show it's complete then?

Comment: The easiest way to show that it’s compact is to show that the metric generates the product topology on the product $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

After showing completeness it suffices to prove that $X$ is totally bounded.

That is for every $\epsilon$ $X$ can be written as a union of finitely many balls.

Choose an $\epsilon >0$ then pick $M$ such that 
$\sum_{n\geq M+1} \dfrac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon$.

Now the points which will be the centers of the balls are of the form 
$x_i=\{ (u_1,u_2, \cdots, u_M,0,\cdots,0\cdots  )\}$, where $u_i=0$ or $1$ so you get $2^M$ many points.

Now I leave it as a exercise to show that indeed 
$X= \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^M}B(x_i,\epsilon)$ where 
$B(x_i,\epsilon)= \{x \in X | d(x_i,x)<\epsilon  \}.$